# Using C++20 concepts to avoid std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, c++-concepts

In the past, when I wanted a callback as a function parameter, I usually decided to use `std::function`. In rare cases where I definitely never use captures, I used a `typedef` for a function declaration instead.

So, usually my declaration with a callback parameter looks something like this:

```cpp
struct Socket
{
  void on_receive(std::function<void(uint8_t*, unsigned long)> cb);
}
```

However, as far as I know, `std::function` is actually doing a little work at runtime due to having to resolve the lambda with it's captures to the `std::function` template and move/copy it's captures (?).

Reading about the new C++ 20 features I figured I might be able to make use of concepts to avoid using `std::function` and use a constrained parameter for any viable functor.

And this is where my problem comes up: Since I want to work with the callback functor objects sometime in the future, I have to store them. Since I have no definitive type for my callback, my initial thought was to copy (eventuallty move at some point) the functor to heap and use a `std::vector<void*>` to note where I left them.

```cpp
template<typename Functor>
concept ReceiveCallback = std::is_invocable_v<Functor, uint8_t*, unsigned long>
                       && std::is_same_v<typename std::invoke_result<Functor, uint8_t*, unsigned long>::type, void>
                       && std::is_copy_constructible_v<Functor>;
struct Socket
{
  std::vector<void*> callbacks;

  template<ReceiveCallback TCallback>
  void on_receive(TCallback const& callback)
  {
    callbacks.push_back(new TCallback(callback));
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Socket* sock;
  // [...] inialize socket somehow

  sock->on_receive([](uint8_t* data, unsigned long length)
                   {
                     // NOP for now
                   });

  // [...]
}
```

While this works well enough, when implementing the method that is supposed to call the functor, I noticed that I have just postponed the issue of the unknown/missing type. As far as my understanding goes, casting a `void*` to a function pointer or some similar hack should yield UB - How would the compiler know, that I am actually trying to call operator() of a class that is completely unknown?

I thought about storing the (copied) functor along with the function pointer to it's `operator()` definition, however I have no idea how I could inject the functor as `this` inside the function, and without it I doubt that captures would work.

Another approach I had was to declare a pure virtual interface that declares the required `operator()` function. Unfortunately my compiler forbid me to cast my functor to the interface and I don't think there is a legal way to let the lambda derive from it either.

So, is there a way to work this out or am I possibly just misusing the template requirements/concepts feature?

Comment: It is not clear how you would **call** the callback. You cast it to `void*`, but how do you cast it back to callable type? Or is it the gist of your question? If it is, the answer is 'you can't without virtual call, and this is what `std::function` is already doing.

Comment: It seems to me like the problem you're having is exactly what `std::function` is there to solve.

Comment: if you _have_ to store them, then you _have_ to erase the type to make that work, so you _have_ to use something `std::function`. In this case, it isn't unnecessary overhead because you do actually need it.

Comment: @Barry `std::function` **does** have unnecessary overhead when bound to plain function pointer (could be called without extra virtual indirection), which I consider a slight defect.

Comment: A `void*` is not function pointer friendly.  It's undefined behavior (per the C++ standard), possibly implementation supported behavior (for a given compiler + platform).  Definitely does not work for the DS9K platform.

Comment: @SergeyA: Where is the overhead in that case? Is there a way to implement `function` with all of its behavior (ie: being able to store any arbitrary, copyable callable object) without said overhead? If so, then it's not "overhead"; it's just the cost of having that functionality. Either you are OK with having your interface constrained to just function pointers or you're not. And if you're not, then the cost of making that possible isn't "overhead".

Comment: @Kevin I think you're correct :/

Comment: The only alternative I can think of to avoid `std::function` would be to have the callbacks in a `std::vector<std::variant<TCallbacks...>>`, for some variadic `ReceiveCallback... TCallbacks` with all the actual callback types you need, but it would be a pain to setup and make for a very limiting API. And there is some cost to `std::variant` anyway, so it might be even worse.

Comment: @NicolBolas my friend had an experimental implementation of `std::function` which avoided extra indirection when used with function pointer. There is no need for double indirection in this case. It still worked with everything else normal `std::function` accepts.

Comment: @SergeyA: If this alternative implementation provided 100% of the interface of `std::function`, then that's a problem with your standard library's *implementation* of `std::function`, not the type itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am familiar with 2 commonly used standard implementation (gcc and clang). Back than when I was looking at it, `std::function` in both of them would use double indirection when dispatching to a plain function pointer. If you want to be very precise, my beef with `std::function` is for it allowing implementations to use double indirections. (I am aware that standard often doesn't prescribe implementation details like that, but it also does in certain cases).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your initial version used `std::function` precisely *because* it erases the type. If you want type erasure (and you clearly do, since you want the user to be able to use any type without your code knowing explicitly what that type is), then you need some form of type erasure. And type erasure isn't free.

Constraints are for templates. You don't *want* a template function; you want a single function that deals with a type-erased callable.

And for callbacks which have to outlive the call stack of the provider, `std::function`'s overhead is pretty much what you need. That is, the "overhead" is not pointless; it's what permits you to store objects of arbitrary, unknown types in your callback processor.